# Need to retrieve top N-suggestions of a word in Solr

Tags: solr, relevance, search-suggestion

I want to retrieve **top N-suggestions** of a **word** from **Solr**. I need most **relevant suggestions** of a word.

`Example :` Suppose if I type "**peace**" then **order of suggestions** will be in - `piece, perce, place etc.`

Right now the **configuration** of`schema.xml and solrconfig.xml`. I get the **suggestions** of **peace** sorted by **frequency** where **piece** word is coming too **far** (at **11th position**) in suggestions list. I need that word to come in **top 5 suggestions.** How can I do this?

[image]